# how to set a focus of Listview item in Metro apps?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a listview in my metro-app.I want to set a focus of last-item in my listview?How can  I set a focus of a listview-item?Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the ListViews `currentItem` property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700672.aspx

Specifically, assign it an object with the index of the data item you want selected (from your data source), and the `hasFocus` and `showFocus` properties set:

```
var yourListView = getYourListViewFromSomewhere();
yourListView.currentItem = { index: 8, hasFocus: true, showFocus: true }
```

Comment: Dominic,here am using json response as a data-source in my app.And am unable to focus a listview item,I have set above properties but still key is showing null and showFocus is false.Where am doing mistake?

Comment: You don't ACCESS them like this, you *SET* them; if you use the index correctly to refer to the item position in your data source, it will work. Of course, if you set this *before* you've set any data, that will clearly not work.

Comment: @DominicHopton How to disable keyboard navigation on listview?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking to set the focus or actually select it? If you want to do the latter, all you have to do is the following:

```
var indexToSelect = listView.itemDataSource.length - 1;
listView.selection.set(indexToSelect);
```

That will get the index of the last item in the list, and then select the item.

Otherwise Dominic's solution should work for just setting the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code to change the selected index of the list view to the last index

1 ) `lstItems.SelectedIndex = lstItems.Items.Count - 1;`

this code helps you to select the last index of the list.

2 ) `lstItems.ScrollIntoView(lstItems.Items[lstItems.Items.Count - 1]);`

this code helps you to scroll the list to the last index. both the lines of code are for metro app

to elaborate the second piece of code :

the `lstItems.ScrollIntoView` method scrolls the list to the specified list item which we obtain by `lstItems.Items[lstItems.Items.Count - 1]` which scrolls it to the last item of the list.